# Scanner returns null instead throwing an exception

Tags: java, sockets, exception, networking, streaming

I have trouble with networking in java. I have tried to read a message from a client over sockets. I use BufferedReader for reading the message.

```
public String read() throws IOException {
    String message = reader.readLine();
    return message;
}
```

When I am on reader.readline() method on the server, if the client kills the connection I expect an error actually. However, instead of throwing an exception, it returns NULL.

Comment: That's because the server is returning null, just check `if(message == null)` then kill the client.

Comment: `Scanner` doesn't have a `readLine()` method. That seems like a `BufferedReader` method which returns `null` if the end of the stream has been reached.

Comment: @DummyCode so when I get IOexception if it does not work like that?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis what does exactly "reaching the end of the stream" mean?

Comment: @Eray Tuncer
You must have wrapped/decorated the BufferedReader around any Reader. Can you please provide the actual reader class you are using ?

Comment: It is pure a BufferedReader :) no extention on it.

Comment: @ErayTuncer Is it initialized with the `InputStream` from the `Socket`? I would think that would throw an Exception as well. Are you sure you're killing the connection before calling `read()`?

Comment: @Eray Tuncer  "reaching the end of the stream" means end-of-file if you are reading from a underlying file. So in-case of readLine() method it returns - A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the "end of the stream" has been reached

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis exactly it is initialized from the inputstream from a socket. I can ensure you it is killed after read() is runned.

Comment: It should be killed before `read()` is run.

Comment: @Eray Tuncer, I don't think you can construct a BufferedReader without having an underlying reader. You must have some reader class decorated by BufferedReader. Please refer to the following constructors : BufferedReader(Reader in) Creates a buffering character-input stream that uses a default-sized input buffer. BufferedReader(Reader in, int sz) Creates a buffering character-input stream that uses an input buffer of the specified size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Eray Tuncer
 it depends on when the connection was closed if it is before start reading the line then yes you should expect an exception. but if it is in between reading I think you will get "null" indicating end of the stream. Please check the following implementation of readLine from BufferedReader :

String readLine(boolean ignoreLF) throws IOException {
        StringBuffer s = null;
        int startChar;

```
    synchronized (lock) {
        ensureOpen(); //This method ensures that the stream is open and this is called before start reading
```

..................
................
//----Now reading operation started if the connection is closed it will just return a null---------
        bufferLoop:
            for (;;) {

```
            if (nextChar >= nChars)
                fill();
            if (nextChar >= nChars) { /* EOF */
                if (s != null && s.length() > 0)
                    return s.toString();
                else
                    return null;
            }
            boolean eol = false;
            char c = 0;
            int i;

            /* Skip a leftover '\n', if necessary */
            if (omitLF && (cb[nextChar] == '\n'))
                nextChar++;
            skipLF = false;
            omitLF = false;

        charLoop:
            for (i = nextChar; i < nChars; i++) {
                c = cb[i];
                if ((c == '\n') || (c == '\r')) {
                    eol = true;
                    break charLoop;
                }
            }

            startChar = nextChar;
            nextChar = i;

            if (eol) {
                String str;
                if (s == null) {
                    str = new String(cb, startChar, i - startChar);
                } else {
                    s.append(cb, startChar, i - startChar);
                    str = s.toString();
                }
                nextChar++;
                if (c == '\r') {
                    skipLF = true;
                }
                return str;
            }

            if (s == null)
                s = new StringBuffer(defaultExpectedLineLength);
            s.append(cb, startChar, i - startChar);
        }
    }
}
```

So bottom line is that you should check for null in this operation rather than relying on an IOException. I hope it will help you to fix your problem. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger an exception manually like this:

```
public String read() throws IOException {
    String message = reader.readLine();
    if (message == null)
        throw new IOException("reader.readLine() returned null");
    return message;
}
```

Comment: thx sir but the real problem is if I should expect an exception from that readline() line.